# NavigationController NavigationBar TitleView is Not Working in Navigation Bar Large Title in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm stuck in titleview When i used Navigationitem.title then it show me in large title but title view is does not show please guys help me for this Thank You
[image]

```
:- searchBar Configure Code :-
      self.searchControllerInvoice = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
         self.searchControllerInvoice.searchResultsUpdater = self;
         self.searchControllerInvoice.delegate = self;

:- Navigation And TitleBUtton :-
                CGFloat maxTitleWidth = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width;
            CGSize requestedTitleSize = [selectedName sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]}];
            CGFloat titleWidth = MIN(maxTitleWidth-130, requestedTitleSize.width);

            if(!TitleButton)
            {
                TitleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
                [TitleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, titleWidth , 22)];
            }

            [TitleButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];

            TitleButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            TitleButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
            [TitleButton setTitle:selectedName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [TitleButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [TitleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(titleButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            TitleButton.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
            TitleButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

             if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
                  self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchControllerInvoice;
        //          [self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar setBackgroundColor:UIColor.redColor];
             } else {
                  self.getInvoiceTable.tableHeaderView = self.searchControllerInvoice.searchBar;
             }

             self.navigationItem.titleView=TitleButton;
```

Comment: Where is your code!!!?

Comment: Please check i have just added code

Comment: Please add code of search bar that how it configure.

Comment: Please check i have update code for searchbar too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS large title does not work with custom title views as you want.

If a navigationItem has both it's title and titleView properties set and the navigationBar has prefersLargeTitles set to YES you will get both a large title displayed in a second line while the provided titleView is show as usual at the top center of the navigation bar.

Long story short: this is not possible.

Comment: Hii, can i do this thing using any custom library or that titlebutton Y position set to minus it anything that helps me .?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Okay ThAnk You so much for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using button in large title, about that I've no idea.

But, when you use default title for large title, you need to enable following properties in AppDelegate's method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setPrefersLargeTitles:true];

    return YES;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Large Title]

This will enable large title for you all screen in default navigation bar.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hii,  this allow large title but i don't want to large my title i want to large my titleview button Thanks For Your Answer